# Pine script : Plot highest lowest price from 9am to 10am intraday session

Tags: pine-script

Can anybody help me how to do script which :

- Plot the highest price level within 9am-10am
- plot the lowest price level within 9am-10am

Both line will be my guide for intraday session ( 1min chart ) and
will plot until the end of session (5pm)

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
//@version=4
study("My Script", overlay=true)

var int trackingStartHour = input(9, "Tracking start hour", minval=0, maxval=23)
var float hi = na
var float lo = na
var line_hi  = line.new(x1=na, y1=na, x2=na, y2=na, xloc=xloc.bar_time, extend=extend.right, color=color.green, style=line.style_dashed)
var line_lo  = line.new(x1=na, y1=na, x2=na, y2=na, xloc=xloc.bar_time, extend=extend.right, color=color.red,   style=line.style_dashed)

f_moveLine(_id, _x, _y) =>
    line.set_xy1(_id, _x,   _y)
    line.set_xy2(_id, _x+1, _y)
    
bool isNewDate = change(time("D"))

if isNewDate
    hi := na
    lo := na
    
if (hour == trackingStartHour)
    hi := max(nz(hi), high)
    lo := min(lo ? lo : 1.0e23, low)

canPlot    = hour >  trackingStartHour
showDashed = hour > trackingStartHour

plot(canPlot ? hi : na, "hi", color.green, style=plot.style_linebr)
plot(canPlot ? lo : na, "lo", color.red, style=plot.style_linebr)

if (showDashed and year(time)==year(timenow) and month(time)==month(timenow) and dayofmonth(time)==dayofmonth(timenow))
    f_moveLine(line_hi, time, hi)
    f_moveLine(line_lo, time, lo)
```